# How to find duplicate rows with similar part of string

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, duplicates

I have thousands of rows in a table. Some rows have similar keywords but can be categorized in the same group. For example:

```
Table : Birds_Name
    +-------+---------------------+
    |ID     |Name                 |
    +-------+---------------------+
    |1      |Blue Peckwood        |
    +-------+---------------------+
    |2      |North Peckwood       |
    +-------+---------------------+
    |3      |Northern Peckwood    |
    +-------+---------------------+
    |4      |Northern Peckwood    |
    +-------+---------------------+
    |5      |Red Heron            |
    +-------+---------------------+
    |6      |Red Heron            |
    +-------+---------------------+
```

As for the table above there should be 2 groups of birds. They are **Peckwood** and **Heron**.

But after I run this mySQL I get :

```
SELECT *
FROM birds_name
WHERE name IN (
    SELECT name
    FROM birds_name
    GROUP BY name
    HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
)
```

After I run the query. This is what I've got:

```
    +-------+---------------------+
    |3      |Northern Peckwood    |
    +-------+---------------------+
    |4      |Northern Peckwood    |
    +-------+---------------------+
    |5      |Red Heron            |
    +-------+---------------------+
    |6      |Red Heron            |
    +-------+---------------------+
```

Actually, I expect any row which share a similar string to be chosen (in this case it's **Peckwood**. So it should have only 2 groups - **Peckwood** and **Heron**.

Is it possible to do so? And how to adapt mysql code to achieve it?

Regards.

Comment: What would make `North Peckwood` more similar to `Blue Peckwood` than - for example - a `Blue Heron` would be? Both share a word...?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(name,' ',-1),count(*)
FROM birds_name
GROUP BY SUBSTRING_INDEX(name,' ',-1) HAVING count(*)>0;
```

[<kbd>**Manual**</kbd>](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_substring-index) for SUBSTRING_INDEX function in mysql.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this.

```
SELECT count(id),name
  FROM birds_name
 group by name
having count(id) >1
```

Thanks

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/92759/2)

Answer (score 0):

I think you can separate those words using [MySQL String functions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_substr), like below:

```
mysql> SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX('www.mysql.com', '.', 2);
        -> 'www.mysql'
mysql> SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX('www.mysql.com', '.', -2);
        -> 'mysql.com'
```

Then, use it in the GROUP BY clause of your query.

**UPDATE :**

Here is my [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/92759/10).